# Way to set the default precision for all ofstreams

Tags: c++, global, iostream, precision

Hi I'm trying to find out if there is a way to set the default precision for ofstreams.
To clarify, I can set the precision of a ofstream I have defined without problem. I just cannot find a way to make it so when I create an ofstream it has this precision by default.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps by deriving your own version of `ofstream` that sets precision in its constructor:

```
#include <fstream>

struct my_ofstream : std::ofstream {
    explicit my_ofstream(std::streamsize prec = 5)
    {
        this->precision(prec);
    }
};

int main()
{
   my_ofstream f1;  // default precision 5
   my_ofstream f2(10);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, can't believe I didn't think of that. Cheers